# remove duplicate from left outer join

Tags: sql

I have two tables.
table A:

```
Vendor  Amount
001      1000
002      500
```

table B:

```
Vendor   payday  Amount paid 
001       190101      600
001       190201      200
002       190201      100
```

can I use SQL to get the below result

```
Vendor   Amount   payday     paidamount
 001       1000     190101       600
001                 190201       200
002         500     190201       100
```

let the distinct amount only showed once?Thanks.

Comment: Can you also show us your current query and its result. (Formatted text, please - no images.)

Comment: This seems to be a mere display thing (suppress a value when it is already shown in the previous row). Don't do this in SQL. Do it in your app or Website. (If you want to do it in SQL, use `LAG`).

Comment: By the way: You should always tag SQL questions with the DBMS you are using. A standard SQL solution may not be supported by your DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely don't need a subquery to use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ta.vendor, 
       (CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ta.vendor ORDER BY tb.payday, tb.amount DESC)
             THEN ta.amount
        END) as amount,
       tb.payday, tb.amount
FROM tablea ta INNER JOIN
     tableb tb
     ON ta.vendor = tb.vendor
ORDER BY ta.vendor, tb.payday, tb.amount DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you RDBMS supports window functions, I would use `LAG()` for this, since it avoids the use for a subquery :

```
SELECT
    ta.vendor, 
    CASE WHEN ta.amount = LAG(ta.amount) OVER(PARTITION BY ta.vendor ORDER BY tb.payday, tb.amount DESC) THEN NULL ELSE ta.amount END amount,
    tb.payday, 
    tb.amount
FROM tablea ta
INNER JOIN tableb tb ON ta.vendor = tb.vendor
ORDER BY 
    ta.vendor, 
    ta.amount, 
    tb.payday, 
    tb.amount
```

This **[MySQL DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e9gpUZCE1nf9t8ZT6SqBtT/2)** returns :

```
| vendor | amount | payday | amount |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| 1      |        | 190101 | 200    |
| 1      | 1000   | 190101 | 600    |
| 2      | 500    | 190101 | 100    |
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` which is supported by most  dbms

```
select Vendor,
case when rn>1 then null else Amount end as Amount,
payday,paidamount from    
(select a.Vendor,a.Amount,b.payday,b.paidamount,
 row_number() over(partition by a.Vendor order by a.Amount) rn from
tableA a join tableB b on a.Vendor=b.Vendor
) t
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=83ccc61b9a8a60e01074be6905f7a51d)
output

```
Vendor  Amount  payday  paidamount
1       1000    190101  600
1               190101  200
2       500     190101  100
```

Comment: How do you know the OP's database supports `ROW_NUMBER` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks i mentioned which support maximum dbms

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin: A grammar note: You want to write "Use row_number, which is supported by most DBMS" (I guess).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks I edited according to your suggestion, appreciate to you a lot

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . `row_number()` is an ISO/ANSI standard function, that has been part of SQL for decades.  It is perfectly reasonable to assume that an unnamed database supports such functions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Um...not really, since a large percentage of SQL questions appearing on this site are MySQL 5.7 or earlier, or versions of SQLite (e.g. Android context) which also do not support `ROW_NUMBER`.  I will agree with you in 5-10 years though.